# JSX inside ternary not returning desired result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

The problem:

I am trying to return an icon along with text if a ternary is true, and just text if ternary is false. Here is my code:

```js
{quote.is_archived ? <PencilFill className="mr-10" size={ 10 }/>  + 'View' : 'Edit'}
```

When I do that, this is what I get, can someone point me to why this is happening.

[image]

Comment: Helpful reminder in addition to the answer below - `<PencilFill className="mr-10" size={ 10 }/>` is JSX, not HTML. You can't just concatenate it as a string like you might to in other languages (PHP for example)

Comment: @BrianThompson thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<PencilFill className="mr-10" size={ 10 }/>  + 'View'`

The first part of this is an object, and the second part is a string, so when you concatenate them together you get `[object Object]View`. What you probably meant to do was a Fragment, as in:

```
<React.Fragment>
  <PencilFill className="mr-10" size={ 10 }/>
  View
</React.Fragment>
```

Or using the shorthand notation:

```
<>
  <PencilFill className="mr-10" size={ 10 }/>
  View
</>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `+` operator as it concats `JSX` with String.

Try ternary only at the place that you want to change like this.

```js
<PencilFill className="mr-10" size={ 10 }/> 
{quote.is_archived ? 'View' : 'Edit'}
```